# Nginx com Oracle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, nginx

Estou com o seguinte problema, configurei meu [nginx](/questions/tagged/nginx) com a **gem passenger**, para minha aplicação [ruby-on-rails](/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), utilizando banco de dados Oracle (*instant client*), a principio está configurado tudo corretamente, porém quando vou acessar o endereço do meu servidor, ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
ERROR: ActiveRecord oracle_enhanced adapter could not load ruby-oci8 library. Please install ruby-oci8 gem. (LoadError)
.
.
.
```

A minha **gem ruby-oci8** está instalada, quando eu rodo no rails server, ele funciona normalmente.

Alguma dica?

Comment: A princípio a gem não está visível do contexto da aplicação. Pode ser quaquer coisa, muito difícil dizer sem ter muitos detalhes.